# The Definition of the Absolute Value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

The Absolute Value can be defined in many ways, but these are the two most common :

**1. As a Piecewise Function**

$$
|x|=
\begin{cases}
-x&\text{if } x < 0\\
x&\text{if } x\geq 0
\end{cases}
$$

**2. As The Principle Square Root of a Square**

$$|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$$

---

In the second definition that I've included here, what stops us from doing the following, and reaching a contradiction?

$$|x| = (x^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}} = x \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \text{Contradiction}$$

Likewise, if I have $f(x) = \ln(|x|)$, what is the reason why the following contradiction can't be reached :

$$f(x) = \ln(|x|)$$
$$\implies f(x)=\ln(\sqrt{x^2})$$
$$\implies f(x) = \ln[(x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}]$$
$$\implies f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2)$$
$$\implies f(x) =  \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 \ \ln(x)$$
$$\implies f(x) = \ln(x) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \text{Contradiction}$$

Comment: When you are using different definitions of a mathematical function it's not difficult to arrive at a contradiction. If you really think the square root does what you've written down in the third equation, then $|.|$ in the second equation is not  correctly defined. Fortunately, it's the other way round.

Comment: What stops us from doing $$\lvert x\rvert =(x^2)^{1/2} \text{ [whatever it means]} = x\quad ?$$ Well, assuming $a^{1/2}$ is defined as $\sqrt a$, the fact that $\sqrt{x^2}\ne x$ when $x<0$.

Comment: A better definition could be $|x|=D$, where $D$ is the distance from $0$, allowing us to deal with complex numbers better without the contradictions you state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I want to thank everyone for their answers here, but I found this to be the most general answer after thinking about this question for a while.

$$(a^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}} = a \ \ ,\ \text{if} \ \  n \ \ \text{is odd}$$
$$(a^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}} = |a|\ \ ,\ \text{if} \ \  n \ \ \text{is even}$$

*Stated a bit more formally :*

$$(a^{2n+1})^{\frac{1}{2n+1}} = a \ \ ,\ \forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$(a^{2n})^{\frac{1}{2n}} = |a|\ \ ,\ \forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

---

Parts of this answer and the intuition developed behind it have come from [Paul's Online Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/), so full credit must go to that site.

Answer (score 3):

$\sqrt{x^2} = (x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=x$, only when $x>0$, otherwise it equals
$-x$.

This is because for any $x>0$, $|x|=x$ and for any $x<0$, $
|x|=-x$

So, no contradiction is reached.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but would be better if you finish saying *otherwise it equals* $-x$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $(x^2)^{1/2}$ is not in general equal to $x$. The squaring operation lost the information about the sign of $x$.

With the log example, it's because you [need to pick a branch](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642212/why-isnt-e2-pi-xi-1-true-for-all-x/1642246#1642246).

Comment: this comment has to do with the linked answer you provided. In it, it says $(a^{b})^{n} \neq a^{bn}$ in Complex Analysis (i.e. when working with complex variables), however are there any special cases in Real Analysis, where it does break down, I'm guessing this would be one of them?

Comment: Yes, this is one of them. When everything is positive, you're fine. When $a$ is negative, then you might have problems.

Answer (score 1):

What stops us from saying $|x|= (x^2)^{1/2}= x$ is that the second equality simply is NOT true!  $a^{1/2}$ is defined as "the **positive** number $x$ such that $x^2= a$".  In particular, if $x= -2$, then $x^2= (-2)^2= 4$ and then $((-2)^2)^{1/2}= 4^{1/2}= 2$, **not** $-2$.