# Does the exponent property $(a^{m})^{n} = a^{mn}$ break down in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, real-numbers

**Preface:** I recently asked a question ([The Definition of the Absolute Value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786221/the-definition-of-the-absolute-value)), on the definition of the absolute value, in which I used $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$, along with the exponent property $(a^{m})^{n} = a^{mn}$, to ask why $\left(\sqrt{x^2} = (x^2)^\frac{1}{2}\right)\neq x$

In one of the user's answers, a link was posted to an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642212/why-isnt-e2-pi-xi-1-true-for-all-x/1642246#1642246) given to a question asked in the context of Complex Analysis, in which it says :

> The notion that $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ has to be abandoned in complex analysis.

But I realized that the question I had asked, which would fall under the context for Real Analysis, possibly showed an example where $(a^{m})^{n} = a^{mn}$, broke down for $m, n \in \mathbb{R}$.

If we choose $m =2$, $n = \frac{1}{2}$, we can see that $(a^m)^n$ breaks down as :
$$(a^2)^\frac{1}{2} \neq a^1$$
$$(a^2)^\frac{1}{2} = |a|$$

---

**Question:** Am I correct in assuming that $(a^m)^n = a^{mn}$, breaks down for some $m,n \in \mathbb{R}$? Are there more examples like this where this exponent property breaks down? Or is there a gap in my understanding and my intuition wrong?

Comment: There is an issue when $a \le 0$ but for $a \gt 0$ and $m$ and $n$ real, using $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$ is safe

Comment: @Henry, so essentially when using the exponent property $(a^m)^n = a^{mn}$, we have to restrict $a$ to be strictly greater than zero ($a>0$). Is there a more general exponent property that holds $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You could have $m$ and $n$ positive integers for all real $a$, or $m$ and $n$ rationals with odd denominators for all non-zero real $a$

Comment: @Henry,what about something like this : $$(a^\pi)^x = a^{\pi x }$$ would the exponent property still hold for the example above and the more general case for irrational exponents?

Comment: Then you would want $a$ non-negative.  Otherwise what might  $(-1)^{\pi}$ be?